# std::bind to non-static member function throwing a bunch of errors

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std

I have a `Button` class, and I'm trying to add a callback function to it. Following the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556773/implementing-callback-with-pointer-to-non-static-member-function) question, here's the layout of my classes:

```
class Button {
public:
    void SetCallbackFunc(std::function<void()> const& f) {
        callbackFunc = f;
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> callbackFunc;
};

class SomeOtherClass {
public:
    void DoThings();
    void SetupButtonFunctionality() {
        Button *b = new Button();
        b->SetCallbackFunc(std::bind(&SomeOtherClass::DoThings, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
};
```

And these are all the compilation errors I'm getting:

```
error C2977: 'std::add_reference' : too many template arguments
error C2955: 'std::add_reference' : use of class template requires template argument list 
error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'type' (Content\SomeOtherClass.cpp)
error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier (Content\SomeOtherClass.cpp)
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments (Content\SomeOtherClass.cpp)
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments (GUI\Button.cpp)
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::tuple_element<0,_Ftuple>'
```

What's wrong with the code? Is there another *simple* way to write what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does not take in a parameter so you don't need the placeholder parameter.

```
b->SetCallbackFunc(std::bind(&SomeOtherClass::DoThings, this));
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I've been misunderstanding that parameter, thanks. However, I still get this error after removing it: `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

Comment: @idlackage That error isn't being generated by this code. Somewhere you're using the call operator on something that isn't a function (I believe).

Comment: See the documentation for [`C2064`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72c1dfd.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Apparently the error occurred because I was setting `callbackFunc` to `NULL` (0) instead of `nullptr` in some cases. Thanks for the help!