# In C++, how do I declare a function pointer to a method in a class?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

In C++, I'm trying to define a type suitable for a pointer to one of several member functions of my class `cBar` (all functions have the same interface, say accept an `int` and return `void`).

For now, I'm making a global type `tHandler` suitable for a pointer to one of several global functions accepting an additional parameter `me`, holding a pointer to my class `cBar`, as follows:

```
typedef void(*tHandler)(class cBar *const me, int val);

void Handler0(class cBar *const me, int val);
void Handler1(class cBar *const me, int val);

class cBar {
    tHandler fCurrentHandler;
    /*..*/
public:
    inline void cBar::CurrentHandler(int val) {
        (*fCurrentHandler)(this,val);
        }
    inline cBar() {
        fCurrentHandler = Handler0;
        CurrentHandler(0);
        }
    inline ~cBar() {
        CurrentHandler(-1);
        }
    };
```

This is ugly; in particular `Handler0` and `Handler1` should be private methods of `cBar`, and `tHandler` should be a private type.

Any clue? TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ member-function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499155/c-member-function-pointer)

Comment: Please search before asking, this question was asked multiple times already, the linked one is just one example.

Comment: Right. An excuse: [C++ member-function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499155/c-member-function-pointer) is not tagged _Function-pointers_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pointer to a member can be declared like

```
typedef void(Trustee::*tHandler)(int);
```

Here's how to use it (adaptation of your own code):

```
class Trustee {
    typedef void(Trustee::*handler_t)(int);
    handler_t pfCurrentHandler;
    void handlerOne(int i) { cout << "HandlerOne: " << i << endl; } 
    void handlerTwo(int i) { cout << "HandlerTwo: " << i << endl; } 
public:
    void CurrentHandler(int val) {
        (this->*pfCurrentHandler)(val);
    }
    Trustee() : pfCurrentHandler(&Trustee::handlerOne) {
        CurrentHandler(0);
    }
    ~Trustee() {
        CurrentHandler(-1);
    }
};
```

Pay particular attention to the [`operator ->*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which is not something you see every day.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/2qJmH)**.

Comment: I get that `:` pfCurrentHandler(&Trustee::handlerOne)` sets 'pfCurrentHandler' to '&Trustee::handlerOne', but I am not familiar with this construct (is this a _brace-or-equal-initializer_?). What is the advantage versus plain 'pfCurrentHandler = &Trustee::handlerOne'?

Comment: @fgrieu: It's a [constructor initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list). In this case there is no benefit, but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Again, may thanks! Another century and I'll be as fluent with C++ as I am with C + preprocessor.