# How to use function pointers in different classes?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Please check the following code. Why it is wrong and how to fix? Thank you.

```
class A
{
  public:

    class B
    {
      public:
        B(int(*cf)())
        {
            f = cf;
        }

        int (*f)();
    };


    B *b;


    A()
    {
        b = new B(this->a);
    }


    int a()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

compilation error:

Comment: What is the compilation error you get?

Comment: You need to use a pointer to member function instead of a pointer to function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ member-function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499155/c-member-function-pointer)

Comment: Compilation error: error: no matching function for call to 'A::B::B(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
note: candidates are: A::B::B(int (*)())
note:                 A::B::B(const A::B&)

Comment: Not entirely duplicate, "->*" won't work here.

Comment: @user180574: You need to google for pointer-to-member or check a tutorial, and yes, you **will** need `->*` or `.*` (and the type is not `int (*)()` and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to call a function by pointer you will need to use a pointer to member function instead of a pointer to function. A pointer to member function has a different declaration syntax that includes the class type the function belongs to. In your case the parameter declaration would look like `int (A::*cp)()`. You will also need to change the declaration of the `f` member variable to `int (A::*f)()`.

In order to call a pointer to member function you need to have a pointer to an object of the type the function belongs to. You also need to use one of the pointer to member operators; `->*` or `.*`

```
void call(A* c, int (A::*f)())
{
    (c->*f)(); // call member function through pointer
}
```

The extra set of parenthesis is required due to the order of precedence of operators.

The following code includes the changes necessary for you to use pointer to member functions.

```
class A
{
public:

    class B
    {
    public:

        // Take a pointer to member function.
        B(int(A::*cf)())
        {
            f = cf;
        }

        void call(A* c)
        {
            (c->*f)();
        }

        int (A::*f)();  // pointer to member function
    };


    B *b;


    A()
    {
        b = new B(&A::a);
    }


    int a()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.b->call(&a);
}
```

I also recommend that you consider using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (or their Boost equivalents if you do not have a C++11 compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use function pointers in the first place when using C++.

There is an easier and more elagant solution - an interface.

i.e.

```
class Interface {
   public:
      virtual int CallMe() = 0;
};

class B : public Interface { int CallMe() { return 5; };

class A : public Interface {
   private:

      Interface *m_i = 0;

   public:

      A(Interface *i) : m_i(i) { }
      A() : m_i(this) { };

      void DoIt() { cout << m_i->CallMe() << endl; }

      int CallMe() { return 8; }
};

int main() {
   A a(new B); // Coult be any object that implements Interface (as yes it is a memory leak
   A aa();
   a.DoIt(); // Will print 5
   aa.DoIt(); // WIll print 8
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You basically move the function to class B. While what I need is to call from B a function in A.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `class B
{   Interface *i_;
public:
    B(Interface *i) : i_(i) {}
    int CallMe() { return i_->CallMe(); }
};` ?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - Both class A and B implement the virtual function `CallMe`. Class A records (`m_i`) a pointer to the interface. The `DoIt` method calls the `CallMe` method for the interface `m_i`